# What's a good compression library for Java?

Tags: java, compression

I need to compress portions of our application's network traffic for performance.  I presume this means I need to stay away from some of the newer algorithms like bzip2, which I think I have heard is slower.

Comment: tell us more about the client and server.  specifics!  libraries, etc.

Comment: For comparison, this project -- https://github.com/ning/jvm-compressor-benchmark -- might help. It compares half a dozen codecs, and adding support for other ones, changing test files, should be easy. It's a collaborative effort.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Deflater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html)/[Inflater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Inflater.html) which is built into the JDK.  There are also GZIPInputStream and GZIPOutputStream, but it really depends on your exact use.

Edit:

Reading further comments it looks like the network taffic is HTTP.  Depending on the server, it probably has support for compression (especially with deflate/gzip).  The problem then becomes on the client.  If the client is a browser it probably already supports it.  If your client is a webservices client or an [http client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) check the documentation for that package to see if it is supported.

It looks like jakarta-commons httpclient may require you to manually do the compression.  To enable this on the client side you will need to do something like

```
.addRequestHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip,deflate");
```

Answer (score 2):

Your compression algorithm depends on what your trying to optimize, and how much bandwidth you have available.

If you're on a gigibit LAN, almost any compression algorithm is going to slow your program down just a bit.  If your connecting over a WAN or internet, you can afford to do a bit more compression.  If you connected to a dialup, you should compress as much as it absolutely possible.

If this is a WAN, you may find hardware solutions like [Riverbed's](http://www.riverbed.com) are more effective, as they work across a range of traffic, and don't require any changes to software.

I have a test case which shows the relative compression difference between [Deflate, Filtered, BZip2, and lzma](http://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Java_Data_Compression).  Simply plug in a sample of your data, and test the timing between two machines.

Answer (score 1):

If the network traffic is going over HTTP, most of the various web servers/servlet containers support for negotiated zipping, e.g., mod_deflate for Apache.

Comment: Well, in this case it's going over HTTP, but it's going to our client on the other end, so I don't think there's anything to handle the negotiation.  If I could implement the negotiation though (or better yet enable it), that'd be much better designed.  Any pointers on how to handle that?