# Java compression and splitting library - preferrably 7zip

Tags: java, encryption, split, compression

I am looking for a java library which can compress files and directories.

I need the following features
-compress
-decompress
-split archives to multiple files based on a size limit

I would really like the following features as well
-encrypt archives
-encrypt file names

I would prefer if the solution was a 7zip library but it's not required.

I know there is an lzma Java sdk but i'm not sure if it supports all the features above.  I know it doesn't support encryption, but does it support splitting archives?

Any library supporting all the features above would be preferred.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about the [Deflater/Inflater](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html) classes mentioned in the question ["What’s a good compression library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127001/whats-a-good-compression-library-for-java)?".

I know the current interfaces proposed by Java are Stream-based, not "filename"-based, but according to the following article on [Java compression](http://www.j2ee.me/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem like this supports the features i need out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

[TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net) should be able to do most of what you need

Comment: This looks promising but it's unclear from the site if it supports splitting archives out of the box.  See this url. http://truezip.java.net/features.html   any ideas?

Comment: I don't think it does out of the box - that's why I said "most of what you need". But I guess splitting a big zip file into multiple files by a given size limit should not be too hard to implement.

Comment: fair enough.  I had trouble finding the download link for the source and library, do you know where it is?

Comment: You don't happen to know about any libraries that support standard formats with all the features do you?  That way i could use the format's standard tools to work with them after my app has created them for example, which would be a huge advantage.

Comment: TrueZip 6.8.2 can be downloaded [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/schlichtherle/truezip/6.8.2/). I've not used 7.x yet.